# What's the difference between sub-docs and nested objects in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are 2 ways of defining a nested object in mongoose schema

```
var childSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
})

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childSchema]
})
```

and

```
var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [{
    name: String,
    age: Number
  }]
})
```

so what's the difference between them? and how should I choose which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing. Omitting the explicit `childSchema` definition in the second version is just an [alternate declaration syntax](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#altsyntax).

The only difference is whether you have access to the sub-document's schema object (you don't have a `childSchema` in the second version).  One reason to use the first version is if you need to set an [option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#options) on the child schema like suppressing the `_id` field if you don't want that.

```
var childSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
}, {
  _id: false
});
```

You wouldn't be able to do that with the alternate syntax.